# Function call arguments

Tags: c++

Can someone explain what that means:

5.2.2 function call

> The evaluations of the postfix expression and of the arguments are all
>   unsequenced relative to one another.

So, if we have postfix expression

```
void f(int, int, int);
//...
f(2, 3, 5);
```

what that mean for the expression then?

Comment: Funny, a question asked right before this one is pretty relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508644/why-addition-of-following-post-increment-operator-is-19 (think of it like `operator+(...)`)

Comment: It means `2` , `3`, and `5` are not necessarily evaluated in that order. They may even be evaluated simultaneously.  The difference would be more apparent if you wrote `f(g(), h(), i());`

Comment: It means that you can't rely on the arguments being evaluated left-to-right, or right-to-left, or any other order you might dream up. Further, you can't rely any postfix operators being evaluated in a particular sequence.

Comment: @MattMcNabb What do you mean simultaneously? How can they evaluate simultaneously if we have only one thread? The evaluations of the __postfix expression__ and of the arguments, so postfix expression may evaluate later than the arguments? Sounds confusing, to say the least.

Comment: "evaluation of the postfix expression" mean evaluating `f` (which, again, is a no-op in your example; a case where it does something would be `F()(g(), h(), i())` where `F()` is a function that returns a function pointer).  Regarding simultaneity, according to the as-if rule the compiler is allowed to do what it likes so long as the output of the program is the same as what the C++ standard specifies.  So a brainy compiler could, theoretically, launch `g(), h(), i()` in separate threads if it saw they were computationally expensive and it knew they didn't interact with each other.

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new compiler overlords.

Comment: @Matt McNabb, "Separate threads" means separate hyper threads in different cores of the processor or separate threads in the operating system as light wait processes?

Comment: @Ramana anything really, there's no restriction

Answer (score 2):

For better understand,

```
class A;
class B;
class C;
void func(A* a, B* b, C* c)

func(A(), B(), C());
```

In this case, order of constructions for class A,B,C has no particular sequence.

Comment: Your code is illegal , `A()` does not bind to `A*` . You could fix this by making it `void func(A&& a, B&& b, C&& c)`